# Pandas Groupby Filter to Remove Outliers From Within Each Group

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing 3 categorical grouping variables and 1 numerical outcome variable. Within each group, there is an n = 6, where one of these values may be an outlier (as defined by the distribution within each group: an outlier can either exceed quartile 3 by 1.5 times the inter-quartile range, or be less than quartile 1 by 1.5 times the inter-quartile range).

**An example of the DataFrame is shown below:**

```
# Making the df without our outcome variable

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

G1 = np.repeat(['E', 'F'], 24)
G2 = np.tile(np.repeat(['C', 'D'], 6), 4)
G3 = np.tile(np.repeat(['A', 'B'], 12), 2)

dummy_data = pd.DataFrame({'G1' : G1, 'G2' : G2, 'G3': G3})

# Defining a function to generate a numpy array with n = 6, where one of these values is an outlier # by our previous definition

np.random.seed(0)

def outlier_arr(low, high):
    norm_arr = np.random.randint(low, high, 5)

    IQR = np.percentile(norm_arr, 75) - np.percentile(norm_arr, 25)
    upper_fence = np.percentile(norm_arr, 75) + (IQR * 1.5)
    lower_fence = np.percentile(norm_arr, 25) - (IQR * 1.5)
    rand_decision = np.random.randint(0, 2, 1)[0]

    if rand_decision == 1:
        high_outlier = np.round(upper_fence * 3, decimals = 0)
        final_arr = np.hstack([norm_arr, high_outlier])

    else:
        low_outlier = np.round(lower_fence * (1/3), decimals = 0)
        final_arr = np.hstack([norm_arr, low_outlier])

    return final_arr.astype(int)

# Making a list to add into the dataframe to represent our values

abund_arr = []

for i in range(0, 8):
    abund_arr = abund_arr + outlier_arr(700, 800).tolist()

abund_arr = np.array(abund_arr)

# Appending this list as a new row

dummy_data['V1'] = abund_arr
```

This should generate a DataFrame with 3 grouping variables `G1`, `G2`, and `G3`, and a single outcome variable `V1` where each group should have one outlier that needs to be removed. We can look at the first 6 rows (a single group) with `dummy_data.head(6)` below to see that one of these values (the last row) is an outlier that we would like to filter out.

```
    G1  G2  G3  V1
0   E   C   A   744
1   E   C   A   747
2   E   C   A   764
3   E   C   A   767
4   E   C   A   767
5   E   C   A   2391 <--- outlier
```

From what I understand, a good approach may be to use df.groupby().filter(), and to group by variables `G1`, `G2`, and `G3` and implement a user-defined function to `filter()` that returns T/F based on the outlier criteria discusses above.

I have tried this, where the function for detecting outliers (returns array of `True` or `False`) within an array is found below:

```
def is_outlier(x): 

    IQR = np.percentile(x, 75) - np.percentile(x, 25)
    upper_fence = np.percentile(x, 75) + (IQR * 1.5)
    lower_fence = np.percentile(x, 25) - (IQR * 1.5)

    return (x > upper_fence) | (x < lower_fence)
```

Which correctly detects an outlier as shown below:

```
test_arr = outlier_arr(300, 500)

is_outlier(test_arr)

# returns an array of [False, False, False, False, False,  True]
```

However, when using the method described above on a pandas object, the following code throws no errors, but also does not filter any of the outliers:

```
dummy_data.groupby(['G1', 'G2', 'G3']).filter(lambda x: (is_outlier(x['V1'])).any())
```

#### **NOTE:** I actually found a way to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50397250/pandas-group-by-remove-outliers), where you use `apply()` instead of `filter()`.

Running `dummy_data[~dummy_data.groupby(['G1', 'G2', 'G3'])['V1'].apply(is_outlier)]` produced the desired result.

However, just for the sake of doing it with this method, what needs to be tweaked to get this to work using `filter()`? If it's possible, which of the two ways is correct/preferred?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731702/pandas-use-dataframegroupby-filter-method-to-select-dataframes-rows-with-a-v/58734451#58734451. The manipulation is slightly different (i.e. exclude above mean), but the core issue is the same. `GroupBy.filter` excludes **entire** groups. It **cannot** be used to exclude individual rows within groups. (IMO, the documentation isn't very clear and leads to this sort of confusion often)

Comment: `groupby().transform` mean and std, then use those to filter with `between`.